# ActionView::Template::Error: Error: "env(safe-area-inset-right)" is not a number for `max' in Rails Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, fancybox-3

I just installed `fancyapp/fancybox@3.5.7` in my rails project. I wanted to override some css rules in fancybox, so I required the `@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.css` and it works well in the browser.

However, ever time I run `rails test`, I get this error

```rb
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActionView::Template::Error: Error: "env(safe-area-inset-right)" is not a number for `max'
        on line 485:23 of node_modules/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.css, in function `max`
        from line 485:23 of node_modules/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.css
        from line 2:9 of app/assets/stylesheets/code.scss
>>         padding: 75px max(44px, env(safe-area-inset-right)) max(25px, env(sa
   ----------------------^
```

Some solutions on the internet and even on SO suggest that one add a sass function definitions as follows:

```css
@function max($args...) {
  @return m#{a}x(#{$args});
}

@function min($args...) {
  @return m#{i}n(#{$args});
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work in rails test.

I'm using

- Rails 6.0.3.1
- Ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-linux]
- sassc-rails 2.1.2
- fancybox 3.5.7 (installed as node module. I'm using rails webpacker defaults)

Comment: Simply do not parse CSS files with Sass preprocessor

Comment: I'm not sure how to avoid that in a big project where css files are required/imported in sass files and vice versa. @Janis

Comment: And that is the cause of the problem. btw, interesting fact is that Dart Sass has simple workaround for this issue while LibSass and Ruby Sass (currently) does not - https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/special-functions#min-and-max

Comment: So anybody knows how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now use [Dart-Sass Rails](https://github.com/rails/dartsass-rails) instead of Ruby Sass.